# Add a flag to a standard shell command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I accidentally found the key of `Meta(Alt_left)+M` to enable mouse support using `nano`. I'd like to invoke `nano -m` for mouse support each time.

```
 ~ command -V nano
nano is hashed (/bin/nano)
```

Comment: `alias nano="nano -m"` ?

Comment: I actually had that typed out before asking on here. Sigh.

Comment: Take a look at man 5 nanorc . You can use set mouse .